# We notice our bot(developed using actions-on-google sdk) show same response two times on some mobile devices

Tags: actions-on-google

We are building Chat Bot project using Actions on google SDK, we often face
one issue while testing our Bot on console it always show one response, but
on mobile sometime it shows double response for same Bot request response.
Attached are screen shots for same Bot flow, one is on mobile and other is
using console, please guide us what is wrong with it, we monitor our code again and again it send only one response.

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const routes = require('./app/router/routes');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use(routes);

const PORT = 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`);
});
```

routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = new express.Router();
const {app} = require('../controller/googleAssistantSample');
router.post('/test12543/gooogleWebhook', app);
module.exports = router;
```

googleAssistantSample.js

```
 const {
  conversation,
  Simple,
  Suggestion,
} = require('@assistant/conversation');
const app = conversation();

app.handle('mainMenu', (conv) => {
  conv.add(new Simple({
    speech: 'Please select Informasi for producing issue.',
    text: 'Please select Informasi for producing issue.',
  }));
  conv.add(new Suggestion({
    title: 'Informasi',
  }));
});

app.handle('information', (conv) => {
  conv.add(new Simple({
    speech: 'Next please select Safe Banking for producing issue.',
    text: 'Next please select Safe Banking for producing issue.',
  }));
  conv.add(new Suggestion({
    title: 'Safe Banking',
  }));
});

app.handle('safeInfo', (conv) => {
  conv.add(new Simple({
    speech: 'Please check issue.',
    text: 'Please check issue.',
  }));
});
module.exports = {
  app,
};
```

package.json

```
 {
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@assistant/conversation": "^3.7.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

[Testing on mobile image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AujEV.jpg)
[Testing on Actions console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfSTr.png)

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to generate the responses?

Comment: hi @NickFelker, sorry for late reply, i have created very basic sample and uploaded it on drive link (https://drive.google.com/file/d/17McUxPovWcI267Z0jregsrvANbCfXzR1/view?usp=sharing) its has same issue as i have mentioned. Please see it works on console but causing issue on real device (Android mobile), thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you just share a snippet of the code in the original question?

Comment: @NickFelker please check i have updated my question.

Comment: If you use `conv.add(...)` with your string rather than creating a `Simple`, do you still reproduce the problem?

Comment: If we are not creating Simple then no message show up while testing (either on console or real device) we only  get suggestions and no have text response like   "prompt": {
      "override": false,
      "suggestions": [
        {
          "title": "Safe Banking"
        }
      ]
    }

Comment: So `conv.add("Some text")` does not work at all?

Comment: hi @NickFelker now i have changed my code like this conv.add("Some text") and it still shows two text messages. It's show one text messages if i use voice commands, but show two text messages if i give commands manually.

Comment: That seems like a bug in the platform unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks @NickFelker, what we can do for this right now?